# Android - Best way to handle glSurfaceView context getting trashed in onPause after orientation change

Tags: android, opengl-es, orientation, glsurfaceview

In my application I have a glsurfaceview that in previous versions behaved fine but in the newest version I allow for orientation changes and that kills the view. I can see in the logcat that it starts back up and all my lights and everything get recreated but the view does not render any of the objects.

So how can I get my glsurfaceview to start drawing again after onPause gets called from an orientation change. Ive been researching this all day with no real good leads except for a link that explains how to rebuild the glsurfaceview class which I definitely do not want to do. I dont care how I do it even if it means rebuilding the whole view in my onResume but no matter what it seems that onPause just kills my views context.

Comment: _Just to be sure_: The code forwards `onPause` and `onResume` to the `GLSurfaceView`?

Comment: Of course :) I've used opengles before but Ive always added my glsurfaceview dynamically in java but this time Ive opted to use a framelayout which is declared in xml and then Ive added my glsurfaceview to that in my oncreate. On the activities first launch all is well and the 3d works just fine until an orientation change or basically when onPause is called. Ive tried to rebuild everything in my onResume but it just lead to errors. I can see in my log that everything re-initiates in onResume but nothing draws to screen. Its like its drawing in limbo.

Comment: Ok so I just made a simple fix for the moment that isnt all that slick and causes a little lag inbetween onPause and onResume but I just killed the glSurfaceView in my onPause by setting it to null and destroying all objects in memory from the scene. I then went through and rebuilt the whole scene in my onResume. I havent posted any code but if some one can point me towards a better method of handling this situation Im all ears.

Comment: Did you ['setPreserveEGLContextOnPause'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause%28boolean%29)?

Comment: I have my application set to run on devices going back to 2.2 so I would only be able to use that on 3.0 or higher if I remember correctly. I also temporarily forced the view to horizontal for the time being until I can get the act of transfering orientations to be stable.